# Can opencv be used for Image recognition?

Tags: java, android

I need to access images from phone's gallery and then perform image recognition like what all elements are there in the images(watch,food etc etc). Can this be done using opencv library's on device sdk for android. I am not getting any clue about this.

Comment: I would assume not. It will probably handle matching against some sort of pre-loaded item(s) but to just recognize something is highly unlikely. This is one of  those circumstances where making a computer work as well as our mind is just not quite there.

Comment: The app needn't to be 100% accurate. In the end i would like to show ad based on the type of data i get from images. Something like we get ad when we visit some sort of websites

Comment: I mean, there are some "working" ones out there, but they don't really work. Google even made a dive at it with Google Goggles. It is just an extremely difficult process when it comes to distinguishing anything from anything else.

Comment: Yes definitely it is difficult one. But can you suggest me some libraries for it and i also think i can't achieve it using opencv. After reading few docs of opencv i guess it is more of face detection and image processing library

Comment: It may help to read the image processing tutorial using tensor flow https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.7/tutorials/image_recognition/index.html - if anything else it should give you a starting point to the complexity of the problem.